# App built by API 19/JDK 6 on a Lollipop

Tags: android, java-7, android-5.0-lollipop

What happens on a Lollipop device when you have a Android build compiled for API 19 with JDK 6?

Would there be any limitation in this app on a Lollipop device? What exactly does it mean when Google says JDK 7 is needed for API 21?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An app built using a previous API level **should** work the same on future platforms.

Just like the Android API is constantly being updated, the JDK is as well. So, the dependencies will increase. It just means that the Android API 21 has dependencies on JDK 7.

Comment: What about the dependency levels with support v4? How could it impact if I keep using the same support v4 from a few revisions ago?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Obviously if you use an old version, the dependencies will not change...

Comment: I meant to ask what if I update the compile target to API 21 and keep using the older support v4 lib?

Comment: There shouldn't be an issue, but why would you want to do that?